# mod rewrite url rewriting into cleaner urls .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URL in to clean URL

the current URL is `mysite/cover.php?name=post title&id=1`

I want to re write it into `mysite/post-title-c-1.html`

Without duplications like `mysite/-c-1-post-title.html`

Rewrite `title-c-id`

I have used this code
    RewriteRule c-([0-9]+)(.*).html$ cover.php?id=$1&name=$2.php [L]

duplicate links can be made like c-1-title.html and title-c-1 and title can also be changed

Comment: Have you tried to make any attempts to solve this?

Comment: RewriteRule c-([0-9]+)(.*)\.html$ cover.php?id=$1&name=$2.php [L]

i have tried this but dublicate urls an be made

Comment: Its better to put this code in your question and clarify your problem little bit more.

Comment: i have updated it now can you help if you have understood what i wanted to say